# .htaccess rewrite conditition ignore subdomain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My main domain is a Wordpress blog, and the .htaccess rewrite for it is as follows...

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
```

This works great, but I have a subdomain in that same directory, and am using this rewrite for it....

```
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.domain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my/
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /my/$1
```

That's for my wildcard SSL certificate.  This works great, but if the location doesn't exist in the subdomain I get wordpress's error page.  I need the wordpress rewrite to ignore the "my" subdomain.  How can I do that?

I was thinking something like....

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^my\.domain\.com$ 
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
```

But that doesn't work, also tried this....

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^my\.domain\.com - [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably ignore the domain by adding a condition on the server name.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^my\.domain\.com
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, a thing I struggled with some time ago, try changing the htaccess of the subdomain to

```
RewriteBase /my
```

if "my" would be the directory it lives in.